# how to make an setup file

Tags: .net

i am new to program,and our teacher asked us to write a small program witch using sqlserver;
so i use visual studio 2010 c# to write it,but i meet a problem:
i don't know how to make a setup file.because i put the SqlConnectionString in the code file directly;so,even i have publish the program ,the sqlconnectionstring didn't change,it didn't works~
this is the first time to write this kind program,and i dont know how to make it work right on others computer;
can you tell me the way to solve it?
do i need change the way of coding?how?
thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the connection string in the config file, that way it can be updated without needing a recompile. The easiest way to do that is to open the `Properties` folder in the `Solution Explorer` and then doubleclick on the `Settings.settings` file, then you get a easy to use interface to create a config file value that you can later reference in your code without needing to write any code for reading the config file.

Comment: so how to install the sqlserver database?import it into the users computer?

Comment: @user353998 - Look at my answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712118/how-to-deploy-vb-net-application-with-databasesqlserver/2713272#2713272